# Overriding logback.xml with Spring Boot 1.5.x application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm trying to write logback configuration in Spring Boot(1.5.x) application.

**Problem -**
The problem is that it doesn't create any log file/folder (or may be not in correct path).

**CODE -**

*logback.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="logs" />
    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/mylog.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each file should be at most 100MB, keep 60 days worth of history, but at most 20GB -->
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

</configuration>
```

Comment: How are you setting LOG_PATH variable?

Answer (score 1):

Either pass the LOG_PATH while variable while running the application or define it in the same file as follows `<property name="LOG_PATH" value="logs"/>`

And also add 
`<root level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
</root>`

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end before `</configuration>`

```
<root level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Where is logback.xml? Is in resources folder? also try adding logger for some class ie <logger name="path.to.class" level="DEBUG" />

Comment: The log file has been created but there's no effect of rolling (none of the strategy works i.e. timeBased and sizeBased) on it.

Yes my **log4j.xml** and **logback.xml** are in resources folder